# Plot multiple curves on the same graph (Color and PlotLegends)

Tags: plotting, color, legending

```
myfun[j_, mu_, sigma_] := 
    With[{kdata = 5}, 
    PDF[BinomialDistribution[kdata, 1/(1 + Exp[-x])], j]*
    PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x]
]


Plot[Table[myfun[j, -4, 9], {j, 0, 5}], {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Why does this *not* have different color?

[image]

I would expect curves with different colors and some "Automatic" legends?

The example [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) works fine:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I would think that `Table[]` creates a `{}` structure, just like the `{Sin[x], Cos[x]}`. So why not have color??

After changing to this:

```
tmp = Table[myfun[j, -4, 9], {j, 0, 5}]
Plot[tmp, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Now they have color, but the "unwanted" PlotLegends.

Is there a better way? Or an explanation?

I want to have the expressions as legends as well as color.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate.  Please review that Q&A (linked at the top) and afterward if you feel it does not answer your question please edit yours to focus specifically on the aspect that is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myfun[j_, mu_, sigma_] := 
 With[{kdata = 5}, 
  PDF[BinomialDistribution[kdata, 1/(1 + Exp[-x])], j]*
   PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x]]
```

`Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` so the `Table` is initially a single object which is then plotted. Use `Evaluate`.

```
Attributes[Plot]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Table[myfun[j, -4, 9], {j, 0, 5}]],
 {x, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]